# Why does the position change when I apply the scale?

Tags: animation, mixamo

I'm trying to animate a 3D model, after I finished I started applying geometric transformations to the mesh... So far nothing wrong, in the end all that was left were the transformations of the character's skeleton where the transformation is already normal, the rotation is normal but the scale of all xyz values is 0.01...
Before doing "apply transformations to scale", the animation is normal like this:

[image]

After applying the transformation and making the scale return to 1, for some reason the position of the skeleton seems to change and this happens:

[image]

But what? Why does it happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you apply the scale to the rig, you are changing the proportions between your skeleton and the measure unit by 100, without changing the values stored in the animation action.

Rotation values remain the same, but location values result to be 100 times higher than desired.

In pure FK rigs (like Mixamo) it's enough to select the hip (or "Master") bone, go to graph editor, hide all curves except thoose referred to location values, set the 2D cursor to Y = 0, set the pivot point to be the 2D cursor, select all visible keyframes and press S, Y, 0.01, Enter (mouse pointer has to hover over graph editor window).

[image]